# How to automatically detect tenant

Tags: php, yii, architecture, yii2, saas

### Scenario

I am working on a multitenant solution in [yii2](/questions/tagged/yii2) following the [Multi-Tenant Strategy](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/603/a-multi-tenant-strategy-using-yii-and-mysql/) walkthrough.

Currently, I have separated concerns for the tenants. Let's call tenants "organizations". Organizations are able to view only their data.

I am currently trying to make a signup for users under organizations. In order for the user to signup under an organization, normally, it would have to select which organization it's signing up under. If I use a dropdown, this would mean every incoming user would know all organizations using this solution which I do not want.

### Question

How do I make a user signup under his/her organization automatically without having to select the organization?

What do I need to put in place to achieve this?

### What I tried

1. Using a dropdown to select the organization: I dropped this idea for reasons listed above
2. Having each organization use a give a code to their users. This would work for the organization's employees, not for the organizations clients as they cannot possibly know all their clients beforehand.

Comment: To those voting to close this, could you at least comment to a post on SO which has a similar concern but more tailored down? Just closing the question creates a dead-end which would lead to another question of sorts. Let's avoid this loop (:

Answer (score 1):

I have based my multi-tenant application on the fact that  `tenancy selective element`  are associated to the user.

In my case during the sign-on phase  an administrator assign which organisation ( or organisations)  are available for this user..

Then if the user is assigned at one only organisation the  multi-tenancy configuration is directly assigned by application  otherwise,  if the user is related to more organisations,  after login in a combo are provided only the proper organisations for the user.

In the case of client organisation  tipically is provided a sign-in for each organisation or a subsequent invite by admin or by app to access to other organisation .. depending of the kind or organisation are related to the client